# Real symmetric operators in $\ell^p$, for $p\neq 2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Consider the spaces $\ell^p$, for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Suppose we have a bounded linear operator $S: \ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ such that $S(\ell^p) \subseteq \ell^p$ for every $p \geq 1$ and such that $S$ restricted to $\ell^p$ is also a bounded operator into $\ell^p$.

Furthermore, assume that $S$ is symmetric in the sense that 
$$
\langle  S f, g \rangle =\langle  f, S g \rangle
$$
for every $f \in \ell^p$ and every $g \in \ell^q$, for $1\leq p < \infty$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the usual pairing between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$.

Lastly, assume $\overline{\big(Sf\big)}=S\big(\overline{f}\big)$, where $\overline{g}$ denotes the complex conjugate of the sequence $g$.

Question: have these type of operators been studied? In particular, what is known about their spectrum? For example: if $p=2$ is not hard to be convinced that $S$ is self-adjoint and hence has real spectrum. Is the same true for $p\neq 2$?

Comment: For $p<q$ the spectra satisfy $\sigma_p(S)\subset\sigma_q(S)$, so the case $1<p<2$ is clear.

Comment: @Corbennick Thanks a lot! I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Corbennick Now that I had more time to think about your answer, I realize I do not know why the spectra would satisfy the relation you mention. Would you mind giving me a reference for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For $p<q$ we have $\ell^p\subset\ell^q$ and so, if an operator is invertible on the bigger space and preserves the smaller, it is invertible on the smaller.

Comment: @Corbennick If you consider the spaces $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, then $S$ (the forward shift) is a bounded operator on the smaller space and its spectrum is the closed unit disk, while the spectrum on the bigger space is the unit circle. Thus the spectrum did not grow when the space got bigger. Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks

Comment: Your example is not symmetric. If you enlarge the algebra, boundary points of the spectrum are preserved. If the operator is self-adjoined, the spectrum is real, so all points are boundary points.

Comment: @Corbennick Thanks! I know my example is not symmetric. Your new answer is exactly what I wanted: the answer has to do with the boundary points of the spectrum. I believe the relevant theorem is that the spectrum of the operator on the smaller space is contained in the specctrum of the operator on the larger space union the "holes" (Theorem 0.8 in Radjavi and Rosenthal's book on Invariant Subspaces.) Thanks again!

Comment: @Corbennick I realized my last reference is wrong. For what I told you to be true, we need  $\ell^q$ to be a subspace of $\ell^p$ (with $p<q$) but it isn't! (it's only a subset). 

I am back to trying to understand your comment: How do I enlarge the algebra of bounded operators in $\ell^q$ to the algebra of bounded operators on $\ell^p? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it's only a subset"?

Comment: @Corbennick I meant that it is not a subspace: $\ell^q$ is not closed inside $\ell^p$ in the $p$-norm. Am I misunderstanding something completely? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Yes it is not closed. But what has that got to do with the question?

Comment: @Corbennick It means that the Theorem I cited (in Radjavi and Rosenthal) does not apply. 

But my question was: How do we enlarge the algebra of bounded operators in $\ell^q$ to the algebra of bounded operators in $\ell^p$? Don't we need that in order the have the containment of the spectrum you mentioned before?

Am I making sense? Thanks again

Comment: @Corbennick Is your above comment completely correct?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: no, only if $S(U)=U$ and the spaces being Banach spaces.